# what is the advantage about mips uasm code

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, kernel, mips, inline-assembly

In the kernel’s TLB processing part of the mips architecture, there are some uasm code, which is another way to generate assembly instead of using gcc.

I don’t know why not write inline assembly instead of uasm. Why? What are the advantages of uasm?

Comment: Some reasons why inline assembly shouldn't be used: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

Answer (score 1):

In a TLB miss handler, I think you need total control over exactly what instructions are used.  (To make sure you only access memory through known-present TLB entries).  Using inline asm for just a few special instructions, and letting GCC spill local variables to the stack (if compiled without optimization), wouldn't work.

The TLB-miss handler entry point is also not a function that should return with `jr $ra`.

So your best bet is to write the whole handler in pure asm instead of trying to make sure the compiler emits a "safe" implementation.

Using an `asm("")` statement at global scope inside a C source file would work but makes the asm more ugly, and makes it harder for asm to take advantage of the C preprocessor.